# What does the 'Ocp' stand for in Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header (Azure Api Management)?

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

I know you can change the name of the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header in Api Management but what does the 'Ocp' actually stand for?

Comment: One Commercial Partner

Answer (score 14):

I believe OCP stands for the [Open Compute Project](https://www.opencompute.org/).

For more info on Microsoft's relationship with the Open Compute Project, see these links.

- [Microsoft open sources algorithm, hardware and source code for Azure data compression](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-open-sources-algorithm-hardware-and-source-code-for-azure-data-compression/)
- [OCP 2016: Building on community-driven innovation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ocp-2016-building-on-community-driven-innovation/)